# How to increase a MySQL field record by 1?

Tags: php, mysql

I know it can be done this way:

```
mysql_query(" UPDATE products SET page_views = $page_views + 1 WHERE id = '3' ");
```

But I don't want to do a select query and then a while loop in order to first get the value of the page_views row and store that value in a variable called $page_views in order to do the update query.

Are there any SQL ways of getting the value of the field and updating it by 1 in the same query? I tried this but it didn't work:

```
mysql_query(" UPDATE products SET page_views = page_views + 1 WHERE id = '3' ");
```

Comment: Your second query is perfectly valid. And it should work

Comment: what error message did you get? your query should work ok assuming your id is a varchar column, not an integer.

Comment: @Gryphius: it will be casted anyway. So definitely not an issue.

Comment: Ah my bad guys, stupid spelling mistake on my part, the field name was page_view, removed the extra s and it works fine now.

Answer (score -1):

IN your second query i think **page_views + 1** is not working together so make it this way

```
mysql_query(" UPDATE products SET page_views = (page_views + 1) WHERE id = '3' ");
```